# Make Mobile version for web same as the web just smaller

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm currently working on a mobile version for a website iv'e built , 
It's abit of problem to create a different subdomain and folder and build a total new mobile version since it hasn't requested.

**How can I make the website be exactly the same but fit 100% in the Mobile screen?**
Once I enter the website via mobile , I just see the logo because it's big enough to fit 90% of the screen.

The thing is , I can't create a specific mobile version , I just want the web to look exactly like on PC just extremely small.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to create a separate version for mobile. I suggest a web search for "responsive design".

Comment: Well , It's impossible because I have some objects like <img src="" width="1000px" /> and <script> $("#someSLIDER#") { height:750px } </script and etc.. so media quieries is possible but I will have to change the whole website which is near impossible

Answer (score 2):

Put a viewport meta tag in the `<head>` of your `html` document

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Doesn't work , the web still doesn't show the 100% it can show , the menu runs off the header and etc...

Comment: It didn't change anything , I added it , but nothing appear to change.